# Django admin send email for new user registration

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

In my project i'm trying to send an email after new user creation.
I try like this in my models.py:

```
@receiver(post_save,sender=User)
def create_user_data(sender, update_fields, created, instance, **kwargs):
    if created:
        first_name = instance.first_name
        last_name = instance.last_name
        email = instance.email
        context = {
            'news': 'Your testdemo account',
            'user': instance.username,
            'pass': "test"
        }
        html_content = render_to_string('email_demo.html', context)
        message=EmailMessage(subject='Test Demo Account Registration',body=html_content,to=[email])
        message.content_subtype='html'
        message.send()
```

If i run my user creation proces nothing appen, but if i remove the `if created:` statement all works ok, execpt for the fact that email was send also when user logged in (i would that email was send just when user is register first time, not when he logged in)

So many thanks in advance

Comment: Can you give the code where you create the model ? I tested with my own model and your code and if i create a record from the admin the function is invoked and if created is True wich means we enter the if scope. I assume you are doing wrong where you save the model instance. Is it possible that you UPDATE and not CREATE a record ?

Comment: hi i put it in my model.py file, on top

Comment: I need the logic of the save() method. Arent you doing that in the views.py for example ?